# What is the expression for the centroid of an arbitrary parameterized space curve?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\gamma:t\in[a,b]\rightarrow (x(t),y(t),z(t))\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrized curve

I am looking for the expression of the centroid of the curve $\gamma$ in a good reference. (I didn't find a good one.)

Comment: Is a 'centroid of a curve' a well-defined notion at all? By comparison to a centroid of flat figures, which is an idealized version of physical 'center of mass' for uniform surface density, I would expect something like a 'center of mass' for a thin wire with a uniform linear density. But ...have you heard about space-filling curves? You can pack as long curve as you want into arbitrarily small 3D region, and then extend a line from it. This way you might add a 1-milimeter blob at the end of a 1-meter line and the 'mass center' would be inside the blob. Is that result OK for a 'centroid'...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard definition of center-of-mass:
$$
r={\int_a^b\gamma(t)\,|\dot\gamma(t)|\,dt\over
\int_a^b|\dot\gamma(t)|\,dt},
$$
where: $\dot\gamma(t)=(\dot x(t), \dot y(t), \dot z(t))$ and $|\dot\gamma(t)|=\sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)+\dot z^2(t)}$.

Comment: thanks @Aretino could you give me the reference +1 :)

Comment: https://www.ecourses.ou.edu/cgi-bin/eBook.cgi?doc=&topic=st&chap_sec=07.1&page=theory